# How to stretch input text to full width? Dynamic PHP

Tags: php, html, css

Trying to make a dynamic url bar on top of my embedded [YouTube Player](https://tsiserver.us/wintube.php?v=79hnLms0vkk).

The code looks like the following, but as you can see the input does not stretch across the entire screen.

```
<?php
    $uri='https://www.playstation.com/etc/designs/pdc/clientlibs_youtube/swf/ps-youtube-player.swf?v=' .$_GET['v'] . '&embedding=0&autoplay=0&sharing=0&fullscreen=1';
    $old='https://youtube.com/embed/' . $_GET['v'] . '?autoplay=1&fs=1&modestbranding=1&rel=0&theme=light&origin=https://www.tsiserver.us/WinTube';
    $keep='https://youtube.com/watch?v='. $_GET['v'];
?>
<body style="background-color: black; margin: 0px;">
<div style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; height: 20px; width: 100%;">
    <input type="text" width="100%" value="<?php echo $keep; ?>" />
</div>

<div style="position: absolute; top: 20; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">
    <iframe src="<?php echo $old; ?>" width="100%" height="100%" frameBorder="0" />
</div>
```

The target browser is Microsoft Edge, if it makes any difference.

Comment: Have you tried `style="width: 100%;"` instead of the `width` attribute?

Comment: Okay now its working... it wasn't with <input style="width: 100%;"> It only works with '/>'

Answer (score 0):

The `width` attribute is deprecated, you need to use css:

```
<input type="text" style="width: 100%;" value="<?php echo $keep; ?>">
```

It would even be better if you put it in a separate style-sheet so that you can easily reuse your styles and they are cached in the browser.